# Activerecord: find record by grandparent value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have the following models:

```
class GrandParent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents
  has_many :children, through: :parents
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  belongs_to :grand_parent
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I'd like to find all Children where the a child's grand_parent has a value equal to TRUE, but I'm having trouble getting the syntax right. Something like:

```
Child.where(grand_parent.value: TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "GrandParent is equal to TRUE"? GrandParent is a model class, not a boolean.

Comment: Edited for clarity (hopefully).

Comment: Ah, okay. So the `grand_parents` table has a boolean `value` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the models in-between to be able to reference `GrandParent` so you would have to join `Parent` first and then filter.

`Child.joins(parent: [:grand_parent]).where('grand_parents.value is TRUE')`

Just to verify though, is value an actual column on the `grand_parents` table or do you just want to get all the `children` that have associated `grand_parents`?

if so...

`Child.joins(parent: [:grand_parent])` should work

if you want to get all the children without associated `grand_parent` objects you can do

`Child.joins(:parent).where('not exists(select 1 from grand_parents where grand_parents.id = parents.grand_parent_id')`

it would be slightly different if there's a join table in between like a `grand_parent_parents` table

`Child.joins(:parent).where('not exists(select 1 from grand_parent_parents where grand_parent_parents.parent_id = parent.id')`

Comment: Yes, the "value" is an actual column on the grand_parents table.

Comment: I get an error for this: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'grand_parent' was not found on Child; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: oops sorry `.joins(parent: [:grand_parent])`

Comment: @bf34 thank you - what if you want to find children which do not have an associated grandparent (i.e. where the grandparent is nil)??

Comment: @BKSpurgeon for that you can use something like....


`Child.joins(:parent).where('not exists(select 1 from grand_parents where grand_parents.id = parents.grand_parent_id')`


it would be slightly different if there's a join table in between like a `grand_parent_parents` table


`Child.joins(:parent).where('not exists(select 1 from grand_parent_parents where grand_parent_parents.parent_id = parent.id')`

Comment: @bf34 awesome thank you - where can i learn how to do the more complex stuff like this?

Comment: Can you clarify this answer, e.g. what if I want all child records for one particular grandparent record?

Comment: `Project.joins(user: [:organisation]).where('organisation.id is 2')` complains about a MySQL syntax error

Comment: you need to pluralize the table name I believe. so it should be `where('organisations.id is 2')` rather than `organisation.id`